# React alphanumeric validation issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

```js
export default (value = "") => {
  let error = null;
  const stripped = value.replace(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/, "");

  if (stripped.length !== value.length) {
    error = "Input Contains Bad Characters";
  }

  return { error, value };
};

// This below code for varying the formats

import validator from "../../validators/alpha-numeric.js";

describe("Alphanumeric Only Validator For Input Validation", () => {
  test("Only Characters Passed", () => {
    expect(validator("Abcd")).toMatchObject({
      error: null,
      value: "Abcd"
    });
  });

  test("Alphanumeric Characters With Space", () => {
    expect(validator("Abc d")).toMatchObject({
      error: "Input Contains Bad Characters",
      value: "Abc d"
    });
  });

  test("Alphanumeric Characters With Numbers", () => {
    expect(validator("Ab123d")).toMatchObject({
      error: null,
      value: "Ab123D"
    });
  });

  test("Alphanumeric Characters With Special Characters", () => {
    expect(validator("Abcd@")).toMatchObject({
      error: "Input Contains Bad Characters",
      value: "Abcd@"
    });
  });
});
```

This is full code i am using in React, please guide me the perfect result how can i verify alphanumeric.

This is the requirement even the below describe code i have written that is for unit testing, but if i am running "yarn unit-test" so i am getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
const stripped = value.replace(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/, "");
```

Only replaces those characters if they're the only ones in the string, because of the anchors (`^` and `$`).

If you want to check `value` only contains those characters, there's no need to create another string:

```
if (/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) {
    // It has an invalid character
}
```

That works because the regular expression will match any character not in 0-9, a-z, or A-Z. If it doesn't match, there aren't any invalid characters.

Example:

```js
function test(value) {
    if (/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value), "=> invalid");
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value), "=> valid");
    }
}
test("");      // Valid
test("0a");    // Valid
test("Ab123d") // Valid
test("0a-");   // Invalid
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its showing error for this below code...test("Alphanumeric Characters With Numbers", () => {
    expect(validator("Ab123d")).toMatchObject({
      error: null,
      value: "Ab123D"
    });
  });

Comment: @STiwari - There must be some error in your code, the code in the answer correctly identifies that string as valid (I've added it to the live example). Are you missing out the `^` just after `[` inside the `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone i have got the solution of this question, please find the alphanumeric pattern `/\w/`. This pattern is working for me, also please find the steps for regex creation...[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)